# Bit masking to determine if number is positive or negative c++

Tags: c++

I want to replicate the behaviour of a micro controller.

If the memory location of the program counter contains `0x26` then I want to check that the value in the next memory location is positive or negative.

If it is positive then I add it to the program counter `PC` and if it is negative then I add it to the program counter `PC`, which is essentially subtracting it.

I am using bit masking to do this but I am having issues determining a negative value.

```
           {
                if (value_in_mem && 128 == 128)
                {
                    cout << "\nNext byte is : " << value_in_mem << endl;
                    cout << "\nNumber is positive!" << endl;
                    PC = PC + value_in_mem;
                    cout << "\n(Program Counter has been increased)" << endl;

                }
                else if (value_in_mem && 128 == 0)
                {
                    cout << "\nNext byte is : - " << value_in_mem << endl;
                    cout << "\nNumber is negative!" << endl;
                    PC = PC + value_in_mem;
                    cout << "\n(Program Counter has been decreased)" << endl;
                }
            }
```

My method is to `&&` the `value_in_mem` (an 8 bit signed int) with 128 (`0b10000000`) to determine if the most significant bit is 1 or 0, negative or postitve respectively.

`value_in_mem` is a 8-bit hexadecimal value and I think this is where my confusion lies.  I'm not entirely sure how negative hexadecimal values work, could someone possibly explain this and the errors in my attempt at the code?

Comment: There is a difference between *logical and* `&&` and *bitwise and* `&`.

Comment: Most bitwise tests for sign of an `int` rely on specific knowledge of the representation of `int` on the particular target system.  Anyway, have you tested if basic inequality tests (like `if (x > 0)`) are actually sufficient for your application?

Comment: As you do in both cases `PC = PC + value_in_mem;`, what's the point to differentiate and branch? (except the debug logging, which can be done separately). Also you described the task to add the value only when positive, and negative, but you are adding it also when the value is zero (which will not modify PC, so probably no problem with that, just your description is not exact).

Comment: And how computers usually work with 8 bit values when you want to interpret the bit values as "signed 8 bit integer": https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html  ... BTW, if `PC` is 16 or 32 bit, you have to extend the `value_in_mem` to the same width. If you did define all your C++ types properly and you do `int16_t = int16_t + int8_t;`, the C++ compiler will extend the `int8_t` properly for you implicitly. If you have wrong types, cast them first explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

1) You're using `&&` which is a [logical AND](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) but you should use `&` which is a [bitwise AND](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

```
// It would be better to use hex values when you're working with bits
if ( value_in_mem & 0x80 == 0x80 )
{
    // it's negative
}
else
{
    // it's positive
}
```

2) You can simply compare your value to `0` (if `value_in_mem` is declared as `char`)

```
if ( value_in_mem < 0 )
{
    // it's negative
}
else
{
    // it's positive
}
```

Comment: +1 for the second method, easy and readable. don't know about performance, but as always, prefer readability over performance, unless you measured the performances you are getting, that you realized that performance is really a problem, and that alternative method produce a "significant" boost in your software speed (which I doubt, in a case such that).

Comment: @GianPaolo the performance may be better, because the compiler understands you want to test the sign of the value, while in first case (unless it has special detection for such bitmask) it will see an arithmetic calculation to do first, before testing. The `< 0` may even lead to optimizer reusing the currently set flags from previous calculation of the tested value, so the branching may compile then as single conditional jump, without any arithmetic instructions at all. It's just important to have `value_in_mem` of correct type, in this case `signed char` or `int8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct types for your values (or cast them where it matters, if you prefer for example to have memory values as unsigned bytes most of the time (I certainly would), then cast it to signed 8 bit integer only for the particular calculation/comparison by `static_cast<int8_t>(value_in_mem)` ).

To demonstrate the importance of correct typing, and how C++ compiler will then do all the dirty work for you, so you don't have to bother with bits and can use also `if (x < 0)`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    {
        uint16_t pc = 65530;     int8_t b = 0xFF;     pc += b;
        std::cout << pc << "\n"; // unsigned 16 + signed 8
        // 65529 (b works as -1, 65530 - 1 = 65529)
    }
    {
        int16_t pc = 65530;      int8_t b = 0xFF;     pc += b;
        std::cout << pc << "\n"; // signed 16 + signed 8
        // -7 (b works as -1, 65530 as int16_t is -6, -6 + -1 = -7)
    }
    {
        int16_t pc = 65530;      uint8_t b = 0xFF;    pc += b;
        std::cout << pc << "\n"; // signed 16 + unsigned 8
        // 249 (b works as +255, 65530 as int16_t is -6, -6 + 255 = 249)
    }
    {
        uint16_t pc = 65530;     uint8_t b = 0xFF;    pc += b;
        std::cout << pc << "\n"; // unsigned 16 + unsigned 8
        // 249 (b = +255, 65530 + 255 = 65785 (0x100F9), truncated to 16 bits = 249)
    }
}
```